# Warp using Java GDAL API

Tags: java, gdal

I am trying to warp a dataset using Java GDAL API.
However, GDAL Java API is not documented and it is unclear which options `WarpOptions` take. 
I feed `-tr 15 15` just like for `gdalwarp`. This results in `Option not found error`:

```
String gdalSource = "LC81910242015182LGN00_B4.TIF";
Dataset originalData = gdal.Open(gdalSource, gdalconstConstants.GA_ReadOnly);
Vector<String> options = new Vector<>();
options.add("-tr 15 15");
WarpOptions warpOptions = new WarpOptions(options);
Dataset[] src_array = {originalData};
Dataset dataset = gdal.Warp("warp.tif", src_array, warpOptions);
```

What is the option to reduce/increase the resolution?
Where can I get the list of possible options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available options should be the same as for [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) utility.

But the options should be added like,

```
Vector<String> options = new Vector<>();
    options.add("-tr");
    options.add("15");
    options.add("15");
```

and not like you are adding them.

See, for example, [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-GDAL-and-OGR-utilities-as-library-functions-td5301865.html) thread.

Answer (score 0):

**Raster image cutting:**

```
/**
 * rasterCutByExtend
 *
 * @param rasterPath
 * @param rasterCutPath
 * @param extend
 */
public static void rasterCutByExtend(String rasterPath, String rasterCutPath, Double[] extend) {
    Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(rasterPath);
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<>();
    vector.add("-projwin");
    vector.add(String.valueOf(extend[0]));
    vector.add(String.valueOf(extend[1]));
    vector.add(String.valueOf(extend[2]));
    vector.add(String.valueOf(extend[3]));

    TranslateOptions options = new TranslateOptions(vector);
    gdal.Translate(rasterCutPath, dataset, options);
}

/**
 * rasterCutByMask
 *
 * @param rasterPath
 * @param rasterCutPath
 * @param shpPath
 */
public static void rasterCutByMask(String rasterPath, String rasterCutPath, String shpPath) {
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector();
    vector.add("-cutline");
    vector.add(shpPath);
    WarpOptions warpOptions = new WarpOptions(vector);
    Dataset dataset = gdal.Open(rasterPath);
    gdal.Warp(rasterCutPath, new Dataset[]{dataset}, warpOptions);
}
```